# Cannot execute certain commands on SATA3 3.5" external USB disk

Tags: centos, redhat, hard-drive, centos7, usb

I mount a SATA3 3.5" disk with a [USB to Sata3 cable](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41KsW-d1-ML.jpg).
When I connect the disk, my CentOS7 recognize it:

```
$ dmesg -T | grep USB
...
[Mon Nov  5 14:38:36 2018] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov  5 14:38:37 2018] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[Mon Nov  5 14:38:37 2018] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[Mon Nov  5 14:38:37 2018] usb-storage 2-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

And the disk is seen as USB Bus 002 Device 003:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm able to access the disk with dd:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg1 bs=1M count=30000
30000+0 records in
30000+0 records out
31457280000 bytes (31 GB) copied, 8.59284 s, 3.7 GB/s
```

However, the following fails:

```
$ sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdg mklabel gpt 
Error: Error opening /dev/sdg: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r
Error: Error opening /dev/sdg: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdg: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? c
```

And `lsblk` does not see the disk:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─sda1        8:1    0   2.7T  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0  16.4T  0 raid0 /local/raid0
sdb           8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─sdb1        8:17   0   2.7T  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0  16.4T  0 raid0 /local/raid0
sdc           8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─sdc1        8:33   0   2.7T  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0  16.4T  0 raid0 /local/raid0
sdd           8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─sdd1        8:49   0   2.7T  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0  16.4T  0 raid0 /local/raid0
sde           8:64   0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─sde1        8:65   0   2.7T  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0  16.4T  0 raid0 /local/raid0
sdf           8:80   0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─sdf1        8:81   0   2.7T  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0  16.4T  0 raid0 /local/raid0
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  31.3G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0    50G  0 part  /
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 394.4G  0 part  /home
```

Any suggestions on how to access the 3.5" external SATA3 disk connected to a USB port?

Comment: First I suggest that you delete that 30 GB file you created on your root partition and named `/dev/sdg1`. It's probably nearly filled up your space. Second, make sure your system and especially kernel are up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the `/dev/sdg1` catch, @Michael. As for updating my system, I just did a `sudo yum update`, but I'm still unable to access the SATA3 3.5" disk via USB.

Comment: A new kernel is only used when you reboot into it.

Comment: I did not create a new kernel, just updated all software. I'll try and find another machine which _could_ be rebooted.